Why binding tasklets on a CPU can be more efficient?
Currently I'm experimenting with tasklets and I realize that when setting a specific CPU for them to run on, the time required may be declined?
Specifically, I used set_cpus_allowed_ptr(current, cpumask_of(0)) to pin tasklets to CPU 0. I ran 20 tasklets consecutively and achieved about 4x faster than when removing this instruction (though all tasklets are still scheduled to run on CPU 0 and their time are quite similar).
I have cleared all caches before conducting measurements, and I also observe that no context switch is done during computation.
So I have no clue about this phenomenon. Can anyone helps me with this? Thanks in advance.
